# How to add a dynamically resolved activity name to the back stack (without using PARENT_ACTIVITY)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-widget

The goal is

1) Start activity A from AppWidgetProvider or any other background task (it is simple).

2) From activity A go to activity B after clicking Back button.

The problem is that I can't set PARENT_ACTIVITY in AndroidManifest.xml, because the activity B class name gets determined at run time. So in one case I need to go to activity B, in other case it is another activity. Seems like I can't use TaskStackBuilder without PARENT_ACTIVITY.

I could handle this in the finish() method of activity A, but it should be a simpler way to add activity B to the "back stack" when I run startActivity(intent). Any ideas?

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: min=14(4.0), target=16(4.1)

Comment: Have you tried `startActivities(Intent[])` with an ordered array of all intents to start the activities that you want in the stack?

Comment: Just did, it works, thank you very much! The only strange thing I noticed is that I don't see any white transition screen between the widget and activity A. When I started activity A with startActivity(Intent) - I saw it blinked.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by that.

Comment: I meant transition animation screen. Never mind, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! I've added this as an answer, so please accept it if it answers your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startActivities(Intent[])` to synthesize your own backstack of Activity instances. For example:

```
Intent activityB = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
Intent activityA = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);

// They should be ordered from bottom of stack to top of stack
Intent[] activities = new Intent[] { activityB, activityA };
context.startActivities(activities);
```

Comment: Thanks! For those who use startActivities() from outside of an Activity, you must set the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag on activityB. Also make sure the transition animation screen behavior (... -> A, A -> B) is as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this , ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);    
    }
```

Hope it helped! :)

Comment: Thanks! A way to go, but not the best one, sorry :)